# Going through sorting with multiple Arguments

Tags: javascript, sorting, discord, discord.js

Can I somehow go through this sorting task with all 4 arguments each?

```js
example = (fs.readFileSync('example.txt', 'utf-8'))
    example.split('\n') //split into 4 arguments
    
    const data = example].split('_').map(item => item.split(','))
    data.sort(([score1, id1], [score2, id2]) => score1 < score2 ? 1 : score1 > score2 ? -1 : 0)
    exampleSorted = data.map(item => item.join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean using forEach?
You can view how to use it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Been on that exact same Website. I don't get it for some reason.

Comment: data.forEach(score => {
  // score is the individual entry in the array
})

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let example = fs.readFileSync('example.txt', 'utf-8');
example = example.split('\n'); // split into 4 arguments

const exampleSorted = example.map(argument => {
  const data = argument.split('_').map(item => item.split(','));
  data.sort(([score1, id1], [score2, id2]) => score1 < score2 ? 1 : score1 > score2 ? -1 : 0);
  return data.map(item => item.join(' '));
});
```